# Supermicro SuperServer SYS-1026TT-TF hard drive red LED blinking

Tags: ubuntu, supermicro, ubuntu-11.10

On a Supermicro SuperServer SYS-1026TT-TF

when I boot Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric

on the last 2 drives the red LED is blinking indicating hardware RAID rebuild

but hardware RAID is disabled

very similar to this : http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=13367

What can I do to make these LED to stop blinking and work as expected ?

User's manual : http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/superserver/1U/MNL-1125.pdf

Comment: Have you disconnected the sideband cable as described on that page?

Comment: I don't have the same model and so can't do the same thing. Also everything works fine on Debian and Gentoo

Answer (score 1):

The 1026TT-TF is based on an [SC809 chassis (PDF manual)](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/chassis/1U/SC809.pdf).  Checkout Appendix C for information on the backplane, you'll have the "TQ" version with SAS support and the chassis management chip, not the "T" version*.

Check all of the cables running in to the backplane in each compute node and compare them with the diagram on page C-3.  You should have a 4-pin power connector plugged in to the top, and four SATA/SAS cables connected.  The 10-pin header next to the 4-pin power connector is connected to your RAID card or to the motherboard, that'll be the sideband cable that the FAQ speaks of.

You may also try a reset of the controller chip as documented on page C-6, though I have no idea if it could be contributing to the problem.

<sup>*: This manual is only for the "T" chassis.  The letters after the numbers but before the dash indicate the type of drives the chassis takes.  "TQ" means SAS/SATA hot-swap, while "T"s usually don't have SAS support.  We're lucky enough to have the "T" manual cover both the "T" and "TQ" backplanes.</sup>